# Multiple traces on Polynomial Regression Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, regression

i am implementing simple polynomial regression to predict time for a video given its size, and it's my own dataset. Now for some reason, i am getting multiple traces for my plot.

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('estSize.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1,1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Fitting Polynomial Regression to the dataset
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
poly_reg.fit(X_poly, y)
lin_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
lin_reg_2.fit(X_poly, y)

# Visualising the Polynomial Regression results
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

[image: This is my output]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: change your second last line to : `plt.plot(X, lin_reg_2.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)),"b-")`.

Comment: That didnt not work, i still have multiple lines

Comment: Is your data ordered with respect to the X values?

Comment: As @Marathon55 points out, the data must be ordered from smallest to largest value. This is easily shown by making a line plot of totally random data that is not ordered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data needs to be ordered with respect to the predictor.

After the line

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('estSize.csv')
```

Add this line:

```
dataset = dataset.sort_values(by=['col1'])
```

Where `col1` is your column header for the file-size values.